# UML Sequence Diagrams. Can there multiple operands for an alternate flow?

Tags: uml, sequence

Im pretty new to sequence diagrams.

Is it possible to have an alternate flow with more than 2 flows/operands?

Comment: There's a big difference between flow and operand. One is an apple the other one a cow.

Comment: by flow you mean combined fragment ? Flow is a word used for activity diagram usually.

Comment: In a alt combined fragment can we have more than two operands or is it limited just to two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you mean something like : 
[image: multi operand] (done with papyrus)

The norm says that a combinedFragment is associated to a list of operand : "operand : InteractionOperand [1..*]{..."

and a constraint is defined :"opt_loop_break_neg
If the interactionOperator is opt, loop, break, assert or neg, there must be exactly one operand."

so for an alt you can define more than one operands.